# Vmware Fusion 5 Port Forwarding

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, port-forwarding, vmware-fusion

I have a service (a node.js express app) running on port 3000 in a CentOS 6.3 guest that I would like to access in a web browser on my Mac Mountain Lion host using VMware Fusion 5 Professional.  I am having trouble finding any information about how to do this.  I believe I would like to forward the port but I cannot find any information about this using either the GUI or by modifying configuration files.  In earlier versions it looks like you might have modified a file called nat.conf but that does not seem to apply to Fusion 5.  Has anyone successfully done this?  Thank you.

Comment: looking for the same info. Configuration files such as `/Library/Preferences/VMware\ Fusion/networking` are totally missing. Did you come up with something?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to connect to your guest from your host, you don't need to port forward anything.  Use port forwarding to connect to your guest from machines outside of your host.  In your case all you need to do is find the IP Address of your guest, then connect to it from your host.

If you do decide to set up port forwarding, you can use the instructions here: http://nileshk.com/2009/06/24/vmware-fusion-nat-dhcp-and-port-forwarding.html

Also:
http://socalledgeek.com/blog/2012/8/23/fixed-dhcp-ip-allocation-in-vmware-fusion

Make sure to put your static entries below the "DO NOT MODIFY" section of dhcpd.conf.

A couple of things I stumbled on were assigning an IP Address outside of the range of the DHCP scope (on the same subnet, don't forget that) and naming the host in the dhcpd.conf file exactly the same as your guest in VMWare (otherwise it does nothing).

You can restart the VMWare Host DHCP Service with the following commands so that you don't have to restart the app:

sudo /Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmnet-cli --stop

sudo /Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmnet-cli --start